# C segmentation fault when using pointer to structure in a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I write a very basic linked list in C supporting only two operations - insert of a node to the top of the list and iterate over the list in order to print the value of each node. The problem I am facing is that I have a segmentation fault when executing. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct linkedList
{
    int data;
    struct linkedList *next;
};
struct linkedList* createNode(int value)
{
    struct linkedList *node;
    node = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
    node->next = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
    node->next = NULL;
    node = NULL;
    return node;
}
//insert a node at the top of the linked list
struct linkedList* insertTop(struct linkedList* top,struct linkedList* node)
{
    if(top == NULL)//the element we insert is the 1st element for the linked list
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        //the first element points to NULL since it has no successors
    }
    else//there is already an element in the list
    {
        node->next = top;
    }
    return node;
}
void iterate(struct linkedList* top)
{
    while(top->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("Data = %d\n", top->data);
        top = top->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct linkedList *a,*b,*c,*root;
    a = createNode(2);
    b = createNode(10);
    c = createNode(23);
    root = insertTop(NULL,a);//these 3 lines provoke a segmentation fault
    root = insertTop(root,b);
    root = insertTop(root,c);
    iterate(root);//the result I expect here is 23,10,2 
    return 0;
}
```

I know this question has been asked many times on stackoverflow and yet I still can't figure out why my code does not work as expected.
Can you please explain to me where is the problem and how can I fix it? Thank you

Comment: In `createNode()` why are you putting `node = NULL` before returning. You are losing the memory that you just `malloc`ed.

Comment: You allocate node->next, then throw it away by making it NULL. Then you make the node pointer to NULL and return that...

Comment: Yep.. kinda too much effort to return `NULL`...

Comment: `createNode()` is acutually `createMemoryLeak()`...

Comment: It is also creating the next node and nullifying it. That's fun.

Comment: You really ought to check the results of those malloc's and you should free them after you've used them. As already mentioned, "node = NULL" is what is breaking your code though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main issues.  First `createNode`:

You allocate space for a `struct linkedList` and assign it to `node`, which is good.  But then you do the same for `node->next`.  So you're actually creating two nodes, but then you set `node->next` to NULL ,loosing the reference to the second bit of memory you allocated, creating a memory leak.  The same happens when you do the same for `node`.  The end result is that you always return NULL for your new node.   Also, you don't assign `value` to anything.

Just do the first allocation, assign `value` to `data`, and initialize `next` to NULL:

```
struct linkedList* createNode(int value)
{
    struct linkedList *node;
    node = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
    node->data = value;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

The next issue is in `iterate`:

```
while(top->next != NULL)
```

This causes the iteration to stop when the current node is the last one, so  you don't print the last node.  Also, as a result of how `createNode` was originally implemented, your `root` pointer is NULL, so you end up dereferencing a NULL pointer, which causes a core dump.

You want to test if `top` is NULL instead:

```
while(top != NULL)
```

A third issue is cleanup.  You need to define a function to `free` the memory you allocated before your program exits.  You can do that like this:

```
void cleanup(struct linkedList *top)
{
    struct linkedList *temp;

    while (top != NULL) {
        temp = top;
        top = top->next;
        free(temp);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer! In the [cleanup] function, you've declared temp as a variable of type struct linkedList and it seems to me  it should be a pointer to the linkedList type. Is it necessary the temp to be a pointer to linkedList and if yes, for what reason it should be a pointer? When using the temp as a simple variable of type linkedList the compiler says "incompatible types" between node and top.

Comment: @traviata That was a typo.  It should have been a `struct linkedList *`.  I've editted The answer.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
node = NULL;
```

doesn't look so good in the  `createNode()` function. In fact, that entire function doesn't look so good. It should be something like this:

```
struct linkedList* createNode(int value)
{
    struct linkedList *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    node->next = NULL;
    node->data = value;
    return node;
}
```

It *really* shouldn't have been allocating more than one node, that's not sane.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to create a node you only have to allocate mamory for one node. Adapt your code like this:

```
struct linkedList* createNode(int value)
{
    struct linkedList *node = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
    node->next = NULL;
    node->data = value;
    return node;
}
```

Apart from this you have to change the termination condition of the `while` loop in your function `iterate`:

```
void iterate( struct linkedList *top )
{
    while( top != NULL) // if to is not NULL you can print its data
        // ^^^ 
    {
        printf("Data = %d\n", top->data);
        top = top->next;
    } 
}
```

And you can simplify your function `insertTop`:

```
struct linkedList* insertTop(struct linkedList* top,struct linkedList* node)
{
    if( node == NULL ) // test if node is not NULL
        return top;
    node->next = top;  // successor of new node is top (top possibly is NULL)
    return node;
}
```

Dont't forget to `free` your list at the end of `main`:

```
int main()
{
    struct linkedList *root = NULL;
    root = insertTop( root, createNode(2) );
    root = insertTop( root, createNode(10) );
    root = insertTop( root, createNode(23) );

    iterate(root);

    while ( root != NULL )
    {
        struct linkedList *temp = root;
        root = root->next; 
        free( temp );
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Apart from this you can combine `createNode` and `insertTop` to one function `createTop`:

```
struct linkedList* createTop( struct linkedList* top, int value )
{
    struct linkedList *node = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
    node->next = top;
    node->data = value;
    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few problems there..

In the function `createNode()` you are allocatting memory to `node` and then throwing it away by doing `node = NULL`.

Loose those statements, as they create a memory leak.

```
struct linkedList* createNode(int value)
{
    struct linkedList *node;
    node = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
    node->data = value;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}
```